# Как с одной страницы вывести данные на другую?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как с одной страницы вывести данные на другую? Помогите.

Answer (score 2):

Для этого существуют формы и методы передачи GET и POST

Answer (score 1):

Использую хранилище данных, обычно это БД, еще используются сессии, куки и т.д.
Вообще вопрос очень неконкретный, уточните его и получите более развернутый ответ...
PS:а почему метки javascript?..

Answer (score 1):

Можно через url, в конце концов.

Comment: ну это и есть метод GET

Answer (score 0):

Передовать ID нужной строки в БД по ссылке

```
<a href="showitem.php?id=1">Подробнее</a>
```